# Get number of documents in a big collection in Cloud Firestore

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I know this question was already asked but I'm being specific about my case: I've got a large database (approximately 1 million documents inside the collection *users*).

I wanna get the exact number of documents inside *users*. I'm trying this:

```
export const count_users = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    corsHandler(request, response, () => {    

        db.collection('users').select().get().then(
            (snapshot) => response.json(snapshot.docs.length)
        )
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.error("[count_users] Error counting users: ", error);
            response.json("Failed");
        });
    });
});
```

Although it seems right, it takes forever to give me a result. I'm not allowed to add or remove documents from the database.

Is there any possible approach for getting this quantity?

Comment: I don't think your case is any different than the other cases for counting documents in a collection.  What's unique here?

Comment: I'm specifying that my collection is very large and that I'm not allowed to add or remove documents from it (and this seems to be a requirement for the solutions out there).

Comment: If the collection can't change size by adding or removing documents, why do you need to query it at all?  Just use the known size.

Comment: This is the problem, I don't know the size. I uploaded 1 million documents but the cloud functions logs told me that some of the adding operations failed and I can't be sure there are actually 1 million documents at all. I need to make sure that nothing is missing.

Comment: What you're doing now is the only way - query and count all the documents. If you want a faster count, you will have to manage that as you actually add and remove each document.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/counters

Comment: What I've shown won't work, the function will timeout. I don't care how long it takes, but if the function timeout, I can't have the answer.

Comment: 1) increase the timeout on the function to max 9 minutes. or 2) Don't run it in Cloud Functions; run it in a Cloud shell instead, or even your desktop.